# customizing treeview in winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview, customization

Is it possible to create a treeview in visual studio which resembles the following figure :

[image: Customized TreeView]

The ROOT , CHILD and Sub-Child , all three would be LinkLabels , and on clicking them a new Form would be opened.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at some 3rd-party component like e.g. [DevExpress](http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Tree_List/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also try embed WPF user control into WinForm. Customizing WinForms isn't an easy task. In WPF you can do it much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You also can activate [Hot tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.hottracking.aspx) for the tree view and then handle the `NodeMouseClick` event.

Answer (score 1):

This is not practical in Winforms, every Control has a native Windows window associated with it.  A window is a very expensive operating system object, create more than 50 of them and your user interface will noticeably start to drag because of the amount of overhead involved in drawing the controls.  You very quickly reach that practical upper limit by nesting controls like you are intending to do.

You can customize the appearance of a TreeView by using its DrawMode property and the DrawNode event.  The MSDN library article for TreeView.DrawNode has a decent example.  It is also a popular component type in 3rd party component vendor collections.  They add lots of bells and whistles to their version.

Answer (score 0):

So, people don't like doing it.

The answer, however, is Yes, you can.

```
TreeView treeView1;

void Initialize_It() {
  treeView1 = new TreeView();
  treeView1.AfterSelect += new TreeViewEventHandler(treeView1_AfterSelect);
  TreeNode Root = treeView1.Nodes.Add("ROOT");
  TreeNode Child = Root.Nodes.Add("CHILD");
  TreeNode SubChild = Child.Nodes.Add("Sub-Child");
}

void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e) {
  const string FORMAT = "{0} Node Selected. Call your Windows Form from here.";
  if (e.Node.Level == 0) {
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format(FORMAT, e.Node.Text), e.Node.Text);
  } else if (e.Node.Level == 1) {
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format(FORMAT, e.Node.Text), e.Node.Text);
  } else if (e.Node.Level == 2) {
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format(FORMAT, e.Node.Text), e.Node.Text);
  }
}
```

Comment: i asked a change for the design ?

Comment: @sqlchild: I don't understand. Are you trying to create your own TreeView control?

Comment: yes sir, the design should be as i have shown in the diagram.

Comment: In this case, you will either need to look into designing a custom user control (not a beginner's topic, but a Google search will pull up lots of information on this) or purchase a third party control that does what you need ...as others have suggested.